# How do i get the range of the current paragraph in a NSTextView where the cussor stayed there?

Tags: cocoa, nstextview, paragraph

Now i need to change the alignment of a paragraph in a nstextview without select it ,so i need to know the range of the current range of the paragraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a subclass of `NSTextView` so you need to access `textStorage` and `selectedRange` different than `[self textStorage]` and `[self selectedRange]`.

```
NSTextStorage *textStorage = [self textStorage];
NSString *string = [textStorage string];

NSUInteger editEnd = [self selectedRange].location;
NSUInteger editStart = editEnd-[textStorage editedRange].length;
NSUInteger maxLength = [string length];


while (editStart > 0) {
    unichar theChr = [string characterAtIndex:editStart-1];
    if( theChr == '\n' || theChr == '\r' ) {
        break;
    }
    --editStart;
}
while (editEnd < maxLength) {
    unichar theChr = [string characterAtIndex:editEnd];
    if( theChr == '\n' || theChr == '\r' ) {
        break;
    }
    ++editEnd;
}

NSRange paragraphRange = NSMakeRange(editStart, editEnd-editStart);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a shortcut:

```
NSRange paragraphRange = [textView.textStorage.string paragraphRangeForRange: [textView selectedRange]];
```

Answer (score -1):

First, get the range where the cursor stayed through `[textView selectedRange]`
Then you can get the line range through `- (NSRange)lineRangeForRange:(NSRange)range` of `[textView string]`

Here is a example code:

```
NSRange sel = [textView selectedRange];
NSString *viewContent = [textView string];
NSRange lineRange = [viewContent lineRangeForRange:NSMakeRange(sel.location,0)];
```

detail in there.
[How to get the selected line range of NSTextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751130/how-to-get-the-selected-line-range-of-nstextview/16755629#16755629)