# How to get the selected line range of NSTextView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextview

How to get the selected line range of `NSTextView`?

Comment: how you decide the line? Is it based on full stop, exclamation, interrogation or the width of the text field you  are using.

Comment: What do you mean by “selected line range”? The ranges of selections, the ranges of lines that intersect any selections, the ranges of lines that are entirely within a selection, or something else?

Comment: i mean the range of line with the selected text. i found the solution and just want to share & note.

Answer (score 5):

An outline algorithm for you:

1. get the selection - `selectedRange`
2. create a range of length 1 covering the last char of the selection
3. use `lineRangeForRange` to obtain a range for the characters making up the line the last char of the selection is in.
4. now work backwards and count - you've got the range of the line containing the last char of the selection, make a range for the last char of the preceding line and use `lineRangeForRange` to find the range for the preceding line. Repeat this process until you reach the start of the text. You'll have the line number of the last character in the original selection.
5. During the above for every line range you produce check if the starting location of the selection is in that line. Note the current line count - which started at zero for the line containing the last char of the selection and is increasing as you progress to the start of the text. When the iteration of (4) is finished simple math gives you the line number of the first char.

Of course you could work the other way around - start with the line range for the first char in the text and work forward. For every line checking whether the start/end of the selection is in that line, stopping when you've found the line containing the end of the selection.

For code which does the reverse - given a range of lines it produces a selection to cover them - see Apple's [TextEdit code sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/TextEdit/Introduction/Intro.html), look at `LinePanelController.m`. Though this is doing the opposite of what you want reading it will show how the above mentioned methods work.

HTH.

Answer (score 2):

First, get the selected range through `[textView selectedRange]`
Then you can get the line range through `- (NSRange)lineRangeForRange:(NSRange)range` of `[textView string]`

```
NSRange sel = [textView selectedRange];
NSString *viewContent = [textView string];
NSRange lineRange = [viewContent lineRangeForRange:NSMakeRange(sel.location,0)];
```

Comment: Note that text views support multiple selections. You should use `selectedRanges` and either do what you need to do for each selection, combine the selections in whatever way makes sense, or forbid the action when there isn't exactly one non-empty selection.